# How to use `tufte-latex` file hooks?

Tags: tufte

From reading the `tufte-latex` documentation, the usage of the file hooks for frequent customizations is unclear. Am I supposed to `\include` the appropriate hook file? If so, do I do so in the preamble (since the customizations apply globally)? And where do I store the file hook?

(I believe it's bad form to ask multiple questions in one post, but they're really subquestions of this one: **What is the correct way to set up and use the `tufte-latex` file hooks?**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not explicitly reference the files at all. If you put some definitions in a file called

```
tufte-common-local.tex
```

then they will be read by every document using these classes.

the file can be anywhere in your tex input path. Start with the directory with your document, but if you want to share across multiple documents place it in your local texmf tree.